# got problem when installing DJIWidget 1.6.1?

Tags: dji-sdk

I am trying to install DJIWidget version 1.6.1 using CocoPods but it didn't work!! and I got my pod version 1.5.3. Is there any solution for this?

I want to run the project provided on Github:
https://github.com/DJI-Mobile-SDK-Tutorials/iOS-FPVDemo

[This is the shortcut image error on my MacBook pro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDuWz.png)

Indeed, my Xcode version is 10.1 and my macOS is Catalina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, I just changed inside the pod file the version of the DJIWidget from 1.6.1 to **1.6**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18xia.png)

However, if someone had the installation working with the 1.6.1 Please give us the solution!